# Strange issue of font or heading disappear in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, chromium

I am facing a very strange issue on this page. Chrome version: "**33.0.1750.146 m**"

```
http://69.195.124.159/~icanusan/faq/
```

Heading "**FAQ’s**" written in **H1 TAG** disappears pressing ctrl+f5  in chrome two-three times.
But the most instering part is that when i use inspect element it shows the heading.

i cannot figure out the problem any one guide me what could be the issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cannot seem to duplicate - Version 33.0.1750.146 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was chrome issue, changing font to web safe font resolved my problem.
the issue was not producing with any other Google font either.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing same problems with Google Chrome. Other browsers work fine.
The fonts disappear intermittently and on hover of link or opening Developer Tools - the fonts start appearing... but mine is not just applicable to H1 but to text in a, div, ul/li, etc.
Seems some bug in Chrome.

I am using Chrome version: Version 33.0.1750.146 m
The fonts are loaded using a css file and font-family used is ProximaNova

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly fine with me too.  Don't understand why refreshing your cache would stop HTML text appearing.  Also can't see anything conflicting in your CSS.  Could just be isolated to your browser?  Try different browsers / Reopening your chrome?  Also using version 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: actually refreshing the browser two to three times either pressing ctrl+f5 or only f5 that h1 disappears and re-appears on inspect element :(

Comment: on other browsers its working pefectly but not on chrome, no doubt on chrome it loads but refreshing the page two-three times raise the issue.

Comment: Still can't replicate this sorry.  Works fine for me on refresh.  The only thing I can point out is that your whole page shunts down and left a little right before the page load completes.  Could it be that it's hidden behind your top nav?  Complete shot in the dark, have nothing to back that theory up with!  Sorry I can't help you further!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me too. But, since your h1 is a google font I would try using the utf-8 code for apostrophe which is

```
&#8217;
```

Comment: no this is not the case, i have tried using this but still heading disappears on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a case of a slow loading server and the fact you are using a font-face. Each time you refresh, the site will need to load the whole font-face file before displaying the text to the user. If you have a faster server or let the user cache the file then that would improve the load time a lot.

You could also check out GZIP which will compress all of your files on your server, this also greatly improves loading speed on your server.

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes this could be the case, i will investigate in this way.

Comment: A quick question when i run same site on firefox it loads and works everything quickly, then i cannot be the slow server issue either.